# Razor, C#, asp.net: how to display a line of pure text after @if comparison

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am doing single proof-of-concept page with Razor/C#.

I have a `select` dropdown list and I need to output `selected` to an option after comparison.

I am hoping to do something like this:

```
<option value="Washington" 
@if (String.Compare(@location, "Washington", true) == 0) { 
    selected
} >Washington</option>
```

I always get compilation error for this.

Any quick fix?

Regards and thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [conditional attributes](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/201/Cleaner-Conditional-HTML-Attributes-In-Razor-Web-Pages) rather than all that `if...else` stuff:

```
<option selected="@(location == "Washington")">Washington</option>
```

If the expressions evaluates to `false`, the attribute is not rendered at all. If it evaluates to `true`, it is rendered as `selected="selected"`.

Also, there is no need to add a `value` attribute to the option if it is the same as the text value.

Answer (score 1):

usually i do it like this

```
            @((x==b) "somthing if they are ==" : "they are not ==")
```

so yours would look like

```
            <option value="Washington" @(@location.ToLower().Equals("Washington".ToLower()) ? "selected" : "")>
                Washington
            </option>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if (String.Compare(@location, "Washington", true) == 0) { 
    <option value="Washington" selected>Washington</option>
}
else
{
    <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the `@` in front of `@location`.  Since you are in the C# context you should not escape the variable name.

What I usually do is set the bit of HTML that I want to include or not include as a separate variable.  In this case, you could do this:

```
@{
  string optionSelected = (String.Compare(location, "Washington", true) == 0) ? "selected" : string.Empty;
}

<option value="Washington" @(optionSelected)>Washington</option>
```

This improves readability and keeps the logic separate from the presentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways to do this, you can either use `@:`

```
@if (String.Compare(location, "Washington", true) == 0) { 
    @:selected
}
```

or use the `<text>` pseudo-tag

```
@if (String.Compare(location, "Washington", true) == 0) { 
    <text>selected</text>
}
```

Note that if you're attempting to populate an attribute of a tag, you should be aware that in later versions of the Razor engine, if the value of the attribute is null, the attribute will not be rendered at all.  This makes it easy to do what you're trying to do with a simple ternary operation:

```
<option value="Washington" 
  selected="@(string.Compare(location, "Washington", true)==0?"selected":null)">
  Washington</option>
```

Lastly, you might be interested in Phil Haack's [Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx).